# What does the symbol ^ represent in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does ^ in objective C mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126461/what-does-in-objective-c-mean)

```
[SKSite requestSiteWithNameLike:@"Stack Overflow" completionHandler:^(SKSite *site, NSError *error) {
  SKFetchRequest *r = [[SKFetchRequest requestForFetchingUsers] withIDs: 115730, nil];
```

In the above code, what does the `^` indicate? I have seen this symbol quite a few times, but couldn't get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH7-SW1)

The idea is to use a chunk of code as an argument. You also can use a chunk of code and pass it around. You can read more about it if you google "[using blocks in iOS](https://www.google.com/search?q=using%20blocks%20in%20ios)"

Comment: Could you elaborate ? Please...

Answer (score 0):

It's a [block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_%28C_language_extension%29)

Comment: Can you please elaborate please... And post a link...